# Split textbox into 3 areas

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to split my text box into three areas eg: I want values to be displayed like 951-05-8765456. Is there a way to display the "-" by default after 3 places and so when the user enters the value it will be split automatically.I want my text box to be as in the image [image: Splitted Text Box]

Comment: In GUI dev these are known as masked inputs. There is a jQuery plugin here - http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: You can use this plugin http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't do with only CSS, so you can use this jquery plugin and you do it easily.

[Mask Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

You can use this plugin for your textbox as follow:

```
$(".TEXT_BOX_CLASS").mask("9999/99999/99999");
```

Comment: @Satpal I already used that plugin so I just posted as an answer. There is no another way using css only. So I inspired to post answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need use 3 text boxes with maxlength attribute with css like 4/5/5, and using css you can remove the border of the textbox except bottom border.

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="Split" tabindex="1">/
 <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="Split" tabindex="2">/
 <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="Split" tabindex="3">
```

CSS:

```
.Split{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width:50px;
}
```

**Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/juN9t/1/**

Comment: JQuery can be used for this. So one input field can be used with `.split()` and `.join()` methods.

Comment: @Rony, I have used the HTML and css to achive the OP result.

Comment: @user876345: i like your approach, but i need to press tab to enter each value.if it is a single text box i can enter without tab.its shows three text boxes:(

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="mynum" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">   


    $('.mynum').keydown(function () {
        var value = $('.mynum').val();
        var len = value.length;        
        if (len == 4)
            value += '/';
        if (len == 10)
            value += '/';
        if (len == 16)
            return false;
        $('.mynum').val(value);
    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```